# iOS 7 - UIWebView extended menu

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uimenucontroller

I want to add additional menu item for the menu that appears when some text is selected.

I have added the code below to `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSMutableArray *extraItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIMenuItem *boldItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bold"
                                                      action:@selector(bold:)];
[extraItems addObject:boldItem];

[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuItems = extraItems;
```

I also have overwritten my custom UIWebView with these methods:

```
- (void)bold:(id)sender {

}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(bold:))
        return YES;
    return [super canPerformAction:action
                        withSender:sender];
}
```

So sometimes when I highlight the text the menu appeasers, but sometimes it does not. I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your array "extraItems" should be an NSArray, not an NSMutableArray, so your first three lines that you added to viewDidLoad should be replaced by:

`UIMenuItem* extraItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bold" 
                                            action:@selector(bold:)];
NSArray* extraItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:extraItem];`

Then add this version of extraItems array to the sharedMenuController just as you did.